# Is there a way to prepend external JS tools in Node/Webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm using Vue.js to build my frontend app, and in that page, I have (too many) Javascript external resources : Google Analytics, Typekit, Google Charts, Intercom, Raven, etc.

Is there a way to configure my Webpack config file and tell it to download the links that are in the index.html (even by adding the urls in the specific file) that would then be appended to my generated js.

The aim here is to reduce the load of JS files, and avoid issues (like not loaded libraries).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you mean you want to inline scripts from a CDN? Or just local scripts that you have been including through a `<script>` tag?

Comment: Those from a CDN indeed, not from local.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I think most of those scripts need to be executed in their origin (certainly typekit I would imagine), so including them in your webpack bundle might not work.

Comment: I know it's the case for Stripe, but maybe not for all (like Google Analytics and cie). If I can reduce the load and the loading errors, it would be great.

Comment: I'm not sure it would be a good idea to append third party scripts like this to your bundle as it would slow down your app code. i.e. scripts like GA can be loaded async without effecting your app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it may sound like a straightforward improvement (less requests -> faster page load) it's generally not a good idea to combine *all* of your scripts into one bundle.

There are plenty of reasons:

1. CDN's are fast. Unless your bundle is also served via CDN, merging these scripts would be counterproductive.
2. With even the smallest code fix You have to force the client to invalidate the cache and download the whole bundle again.
3. Popular scripts (like GA) might have been already cached by user's browser, so they won't be downloaded at all.
4. Third party scripts have a tendency to a) be updated b) load other scripts. So if you bundle one specific version of such a script, it could become broken the moment after.

### What can be done

Most of these scripts are not crucial to the page render, so you could

1. Load the scripts in a non-blocking manner.
2. Load the scripts *after* the page is fully rendered.

### I understand the consequences, but I really need to bundle those scripts!

Apparently, you [could not](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/150#issuecomment-32756166) bundle remote script with webpack:

> webpack is a module bundler not a javascript loader. It package files from local disk and don't load files from the web (except its own chunks).
>
> Use a javascript loader, i. e. [script.js](https://github.com/ded/script.js).

```
var $script = require("scriptjs");

$script("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js", function() {
    // ...
});
```

However, You can [prepend your bundle with external scripts](https://fettblog.eu/gulp-merge-cdn-files-into-your-pipeline/) using some kind of task runner, like gulp or grunt.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var request = require('request');
var merge = require('merge2');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var buffer = require('gulp-buffer');

gulp.task('js', function() {
  var jquery = request('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js').pipe(source('jquery.js'));
  var main = gulp.src('main.js');

  return merge(jquery, main)
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(concat('concat.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Since You could [integrate](https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-gulp.html) webpack into your building pipeline, it seems like a fairy decent approach.

Comment: I like your points, even though in my case somes are not correct, it applies greatly with the general cases. For example in my case, the libraries that cause troubles is thoses that I interact with (Intercom, which I send requests too from within the code), Raven (for getsentry.com, which I connects to it when my js loads). For those two, I need them to be ready BEFORE my script is ready, or I'll have errors (and that's the case), hence my question :)

Comment: But I agree that for GA, Typekit, your answer applies perfectly well :)

Comment: @CyrilN. I've updated the answer with the working solution

Comment: `Popular scripts (like GA) might have been already cached by user's browser, so they won't be downloaded at all.` Great idea. I was about to ask if I could bundle GA code with webpack somehow.